# why laravel blade @yield adds a new line (line break)

Tags: php, laravel, template-engine, laravel-blade

I'm using `blade templating` with `laravel 4.2`

I have a little issue with the `@yield` function which works with the `@section` function.

Let's say in my layout template `layout.blade.php` I have the following statement:

```
<meta name="description" content="@yield('description')">
```

and in `contact.blade.php` which extends `layout.blade.php` I have this:

```
@section('description')
    this is the contact page
@stop
```

The output is this:

```
<meta name="description" content="this is the contact page
">
```

The problem is the `line break` added automatically at the end the section rendering.

Do you have an idea how to avoid this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried `@section('description')this is the contact page@stop` with no newlines? Alternatively, have you tried not caring? The new line shouldn't break anything.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried this, but it broke the code because **@section** and **@stop** functions cannot be in the same line.

Comment: Darn, that's a pity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `@yield` and `@section` where not meant to be used as a variable but rather for replacing parts of the content according to the needs of each derived page.

To accomplish that you should either pass a parameter to your blade `view` from the `controller` like:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ $page_description }}">
```

or consider replacing the whole meta tag(s) for that page, ie:

**layout.blade.php**

```
<meta name="title" content="This is my page title for all pages">
@yield("additional_meta_tags")
```

**contact.blade.php** (or other pages)

```
@section("additional_meta_tags")
    <meta name="description" content="this is the contact page">
@stop
```

Comment: Well, It's not the ideal solution but I'll take it. Because passing the values of keywords, description, body ID... all through the controller to the view is not a good idea. I take rather the second alternative, because it works just fine even if a bit more of code.

Comment: Passing an array of values from controller to the view **is a good idea** and the only good idea you can implement. Anything else is, well, not good, simply by logic of things. I really can't see how an entire block is easier to handle for variables than a simple array that you can use any way you like. +1 for the valid answer.

Comment: @Kypros: Can you please check [Pavel's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614963/why-laravel-blade-yield-adds-a-new-line-line-break#answer-27460056) answer and mention if there is anything wrong. I find his answer as perfect solution to my problem.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `{{trim(View::yieldContent('description'))}}`

### The explanation.

I had the same problem. I had a few modal windows on the page, that had a common layout but different bodies, titles and "id" attributes. So, "id" attribute should be yielded without any spaces around.

The `@yield` statement compiles to `echo $__env->yieldContent` call (BladeCompiler.php, compileYield method). `$_env` here is an instance of `\Illuminate\View\Factory`. So you can use `{{trim(View::yieldContent('description'))}}` where View is a facade.

Comment: The only perfect answer I found.

Answer (score 18):

From Laravel 5 onwards, the solution I like most is:

```
@section('description', 'this is the contact page')
```

Comment: Super helpful for 5! Thanks